# Problem with simple onClick action

Tags: java, android

Simple code which is copied from web doesnt seem to be working. There is no action when i click button but text of it is correctly changed. What's wrong?

```
package android.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class main extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button closeButton = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        closeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Klik!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
        });
        closeButton.setText("dupa");
    }
}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />
<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/button"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks for any help,
Chris

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call .show() on your Toast.

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Klik!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
```